# iPhone SDK: Play a single WAV from a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, wav

I am currently trying out this code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dream" ofType:@"m4a"];  
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];  
theAudio.delegate = self;  
[theAudio play];
```

However, the SDK says that the ViewController does not implement the AVAudioPlayer Delegate.

Any body any ideas on how to play a WAV (or M4a) using the 2.2 SDK?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>` to the end of your controller's class declaration, along these lines:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

This'll probably generate some more warnings about delegate methods you need to implement - follow those and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Don't forget about adding the `AudioToolbox` and `AVFoundation` frameworks to your project, and importing `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` and `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` in your view controller delegate file.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Try `NSURL -URLWithString:` - that's what I use in combination with the bundle method you're using. I don't see anything that could be causing a problem other than that. You're testing it on the device, right?

Answer (score 1):

The answer [I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195581/latency-between-different-sounds-in-iphone-application/6196472#6196472) should definitely help you. Just use audioservices for small wave sounds, unless you need concurrency, it's faster.

Answer (score -1):

iPhoneToot.com has its own itootSound class and a VIDEO to show you how to play a wav file in 2 lines of code.  Check them out at iPhoneToot.com.  it will save you hours if not days of time!!