# Latency between different sounds in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio, latency

I’m trying to make a small iPhone application with some buttons to play WAV sounds.
My buttons works, but I have a small latency (~ 0,5 sec).

**This is my .m file :**

```
#import "buttonSoundViewController.h"

@implementation buttonSoundViewController
//@synthesize player;

-(IBAction) playSoundA:(id)sender{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

-(IBAction) playSoundB:(id)sender{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [player release];
}

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error {
}

-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player {
}

-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player {
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [audioPlayer release];
    [super dealloc];
}   

@end
```

How can I avoid this latency between playing different sounds?

Comment: are the WAV files large? Try using a smaller file type and see if it improves the load time

Comment: @Mark No my WAV files are light (1 sec, ~ 500 Kb).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using AudioServices is indeed much quicker for small sounds (less than 30 seconds). The required code isn't very long either (but it requires some good old C).

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

SystemSoundID soundID = 0;
NSString* str =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil];
CFURLRef soundFileURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:str ];
OSStatus errorCode = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURL, &soundID);
if (errorCode != 0) {
    // Handle failure here
}
else
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Also you can optimize your sounds (reduce their size) with the following terminal command:

```
afconvert mysound.caf mysoundcompressed.caf -d ima4 -f caff
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I'm not enough good on Ob-C to understand how to implement AudioServices... I'm a noob. Do you think the trick by Hotpaw2 can be working for me ? I do not know how to apply.

Comment: All you need is to add the AudioServices.framework to your XCode project (in project settings in XCode 4). Then the code above will work as is.

Comment: Thank you but I have not found AudioServices.Framework. If it's in AudioToolbox, I added this one. Or maybe I'm stupid... I don't even know what to do with the code above... Where to place, how link my WAV files, etc. Objective-C is a nightmare. I regularly develop in .NET and Delphi and it's intuitive. Not Objective-C. I waste an incredible time (two full days) to look for basic stuff... I'm exhausted. I prefer to pay someone to make me a ready XCode project with which I could understand how it works quietly. If interested...

Comment: Oops. Sorry the framework's name for audio services IS audiotoolbox. Doesn't the code above work for you?

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed it to `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` instead.

Comment: System sounds are no different you also get latency.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify things a lot by using system sounds.  Look up: `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` in the documentation.  There is also a "System Sound Services Reference Document" that talks about that and other related functions.  This is a simple and efficient way to play short sounds. Not sure if it will solve your latency issues but its a good start.  You may also try using some different sound file types.  Perhaps there is an issue with how it was or was not compressed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could look at [AppSoundEngine](https://github.com/CocoaMiners/AppSoundEngine). It addresses latency and greatly simplifies using of System Sound Services, because it is objective-c wrapper for SystemSoundID and associated C functions.

You can not get acceptable latency (<10 ms) from AVAudioPlayer. System Sound Services is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple Docs grab the SoundEffect class in project BubbleLevel

*SoundEffect is a simple Objective-C wrapper around Audio Services
functions that allow the loading and playing of sound files.*

Classes/SoundEffect.m

this will make playing files as easy as

```
  SoundEffect *soundEffect = [SoundEffect soundEffectWithContentsOfFile:@""]
  [soundEffect play];
```

it will also handle memory deallocation. AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);

Answer (score 0):

One simple fix would just be to do the AVAudioPlayer alloc init for the 2 sounds in your buttonSoundViewController's init method.  Then those 2 audio players will already be ready to play in your button delegates.

The fastest way to play sounds is to use the RemoteIO Audio Unit, but that's a far more advanced and complicated looking API.

Comment: Thank you everybody, I will look all this replies !
I'll keep in touch this thread.

Comment: Hi Hotpaw2, I can not find where and how to place AVAudioPlayer alloc init... I'm a bit lost :s

Comment: @Beny : Did you create instance variables in your view controller to save your 2 av players for later use?